# determine file type/extension of uploaded file in java

Tags: java

i am trying to figure out a way to determine the file type of a file which i upload in my struts2 application. my application can read CSV and XML files and perform operations depending on what type of file was uploaded. i am taking the file as an instance of "File" class. the file is never copied onto the system.

i want to know how to determine the type/content of the uploaded file. i tried the following piece of code to see if i get the file type:

```
String extension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(file.getAbsolutePath);
```

logging extension gave me the extension as "tmp".
what can i do to get the file extension?

Answer (score 3):

If you use Java 7, you can use [`Files.probeContentType()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#probeContentType-java.nio.file.Path-). It is not lured by extensions...

The JDK has a number of file formats recognized as a default; this may be enough for you.

Otherwise, well, it is extensible!

Usage:

```
Files.probeContentType(file.toPath().toAbsolutePath())
```

Comment: i am getting file extension as 'null' using this :/

Comment: It means the content type cannot be determined... Then jmimemagic looks like the solution.

Comment: i tried jmimemagic. i t gives the MimeType as text/plain for both CSV and XML files

Comment: note it depends on the registered Detectors if the detection will be **based on the file name or contents**

Answer (score 0):

Check the following library: http://jmimemagic.sourceforge.net/index.html

It should be the one you need. Also you may consider the [following review](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0487.html) which covers a lot of libraries of that kind.

Actually all modern Unix-like systems have `file` utility which checks a given file *content* and report its type according to its database (`/etc/magic` or `/usr/share/file/magic`). But this approach involves dependency on an external system functrionality which may be inaccessible for you.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    File f = new File("d:/sample.txt");
    System.out.println(getExtention(f.getAbsolutePath()));
}

public static String getExtention(String file){
    if(null == file  || !file.contains(".")){
        return null;
    }else{
        return file.substring(file.lastIndexOf("."));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i found out the solution. as i am using struts, i just had to create a new setter method. If the file object was X, i had to create a setter method

```
setXFileName(String fileName){
this.xFileName = fileName;
}
```

struts does the rest

Answer (score -1):

you can try to get the extension from this

```
private String getFileExt(File file) {
String name = file.getName();
try {
    return name.substring(name.lastIndexOf("."));

} catch (Exception e) {
    return "";
}
```

}